# The code behind filesystem.normalize

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and OOP. I have a strange disorder that makes me extremely curious how things work. So I copied this code that use normalize() and I'm trying to get the source code of it but all I found is

```
public abstract String normalize(String path);
```

In:

FileSystem.java file

Of course, know what it does. But I'm curious how and why i cant find the code behind it.

Thank you
Michal

Comment: That's the declaration. The implementation will be elsewhere.

Comment: Do you understand the meaning of [`abstract`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html)?

Comment: @Carcigenicate - Where?

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels - That's explains why i couldn't find it

Comment: @PM 77-1 - Not yet

Comment: .... but I could be wrong as I have not searched for this source.

Comment: You should be able to find a more concrete implementation method for normalize, and inside it, it will say if it makes native calls.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using an IDE (like Eclipse), you can use it to find the concrete implementations of that method.

In Eclipse:

1. <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + T</kbd> and type `java.io.FileSystem`; click "OK"
2. Hover over the `normalize` method name. A menu will appear like below.
   [image: hover Ctrl click method name]]
3. Click "Open Implementation"

   - If there is more than one implementation available, you will see a list. Click on the one you want to open.
   - If there is only one, then that single implementation will be opened automatically.

   [image: Windows implementation of normalize method]

Comment: Thank you! It's broken in my eclipse but i will figure it out!